# SP workflow designer with imperrsonation step: replace item permissions - people picker

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

SP online
workflow 2010 template with impersonation step

The workflow reads a column value in the item that is entered by the user. People picker can be one or multiple values (it is mandatory)

When it is one person workflow works, when it is multiple people it throws error.

In the workflow I have tried all (as string, email addresses semicolon delimited, display names etc), it always gives error

how to make the workflow read the multiple people field?

Comment: Can you please add any screenshot of the workflow action, how are you configuring the action? Also check the solutions given [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/50725/error-occurred-when-assigning-permission-to-multiple-user-in-impersonation-step) (especially creating a string variable and then using it to assign the permissions) and let me know if this works.

Comment: I have done the variable as explained and now it works, any reason why it does not work directly with multiple people with the standard options? I do remember that when the action is 'send an email' it does work

Comment: For "send an email" option, semicolon separated email addresses are required so it works. and for assigning permissions, I am not quite sure but maybe it is bug in action or it is designed in that way only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following approach to replace item permissions:

1. Set a STRING variable to the multiple selection people picker field, returning the field as a STRING.
2. In an Impersonation Step, add the action to Add/replace item permissions and use the string variable you just created in above step.